# How to calculate how far radio light goes in the ocean

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, dielectric, radio, radio-frequency

Radio light is not a practically useful way of communicating underwater over large distances. My question is how does one calculate how far a radio wave at a given frequency will propaagate in the ocean before it is made effectively useless by the high dielectric nature of the seawater?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the exact formula for the attenuation of E&M waves in a conducting material can easily be found in most textbooks on applied E&M.

Answer (score 3):

the standard estimate is that by the time the EM wave has traveled into the water by ~a small fraction of one wavelength, it has been more or less completely absorbed.

This means it is possible to penetrate water to a measurable depth with EM waves of extremely long wavelength- thousands or tens of thousands of meters. *Extra low frequency* radio has used to send signals to submerged submarines in this way.

Comment: Some have said that higher frequency radio waves can penetrate for yards and still be useful. Also, RC submarines exist.

Comment: do rc subs function in salt water?

Comment: I could not find any indications that they could function in anything deeper than about 10 feet or so in freshwater.

Comment: probably zero feet in salt water.